# Clarification on decimals and ERC20 token amount

Tags: contract-development, tokens, erc-20

I am creating an ERC20 token and have specified `decimal` as 2 since the token can have values like 10.32

When I minted 1000 coins using smart contract invocation from my dapp, I got 10 coins in my wallet. Shall I assume that in mint function inside smart contract, I should multiple amount with 100 (due to 2 decimals) before actual number of coins are minted? Or is there another way to handle this?

**Update**: I invoked `balanceOf` method and it returns the balance correctly as 1000 without any conversion but in my dapp, it shows as 10.

Answer (score 4):

Since `EVM` cannot handle decimals, you need to specify decimals. So when you say your token has 2 decimals, this means the min unit of your token exists is `0.01`.

So the value you say Mint amount is 1000 (it actually `1000/(10^2)`).

In short, if you need to send/transfer/mint **n** tokens you have to pass **n*(10^decimals).**

In your case, if you want to mint 1000 tokens you have to pass 1000 * 100 to your function parameter.

Comment: When you say **function parameter**, do you mean smart contract method which mints the coin or the frontend where user is asked how many coins need to be minted? I am trying to understand where exactly this conversion need to be done - in smart contracts or outside?

Comment: When I mean function param, I mean the contract function. You can modify your frontend in a way that when user enters a value n you make it 100*n  (as you have 2 decimal places) as your UI can take decimal values. But your smart contract should get 100*n.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. One last thing, when I use `balanceOf` method of ERC20, I get the correct amount of tokens that I intended to mint but MetaMask wallet shows balance as N / 10^2. Why this discrepancy?

Comment: This is because some wallets or I should say UI already implements this. So when you want to mint `n` tokens you multiply it by `10^decimasl` and when you retrieve balance you must see `n` that is why most wallets divide the balance you receive by `10^decimals`

Comment: Since Solidity doesn't support floating numbers, how do we handle them. For example, in my case token amounts could be 75.62 or 1015.50 but when they `transfer` function is called with these amounts, smart contract converts this to integer (I assume, to 75 and 1015 respectively). How to make that work?

Comment: Your smart contract doesn't make any changes but your wallet does. Like if you have specified `decimal places` while creating token to be **2**. When you try to transfer `76.62`, the wallet (or UI) multiplies this by `10^2` and then calls contract's transfer function. So contract receives `7662` as it's amount parameter. And when you retrieve balance most wallet divide the balance by 100 (in coin with 2 decimals), so that you again see 76.62 in your account.

Answer (score 0):

The ether blockchain uses unsigned integer (uint)  which doesn't accept decimals. So you need to mention the number of decimal places in your token. based on that the ether blockchain will take the decimal places from the last digit.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the content of the answers given are correct I would like to point out that in this case in order to avoid under/overflow you can use maths from ethers/web3

```
const d = new ethers.BigNumber.from(10).pow(decimals)
const amount = (new ethers.BigNumber.from(1000)).mul(d)
```

Generally is better to use such functions to make calculation especially in case of big magnitude numbers.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62048923/erc20-contract-not-able-to-transfer-large-tokens)